# LibreOffice removed (&uninstallable) after Ubuntu 14.04.4 snapshot update

Tags: updates, libreoffice, snapshot

After having accepted the newest updates for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS a "snapshot" (didn't know what this was) was installed. After the recommended reboot the system restarted without LibreOffice.

Re-installation following the  [officially recommeded](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice) path didn't work. The code is here:

```
a@a-Aspire:~$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.4.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1~c42.ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-draw but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-report-builder-bin but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:4.4.2~) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed or
                           libreoffice-kde but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to  correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help me to reinstall LibreOffice. Thanks :)

Comment: Try to fix your packages: sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: @DnrDevil : Thank you! Attempt seemed unsuccessful. See response above.

Comment: It was successful run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade : install recommend then you should be ready to install office

Comment: @DnrDevil OK! :) After the recommended lines installation `sudo apt-get install libreoffice` worked. Thank you!
Can you please add a brief response in order to recommend the solution for others.

Comment: Added an answer as requested; )

Comment: Anyone has any idea about "snapshot" in the title?

Comment: @DKBose Thanks. "Snapshot" is the [official term](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/)* for an "larger update" which includes all previous updates of an distribution. Since it the LibreOffice issue occurred after such a "snapshot" (not an update) it should be specified.
* [Here](https://ikhaya.ubuntuusers.de/2016/02/19/vierter-snapshot-von-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-veroeffentlicht/) you can find more specific explanations (German).

Comment: Thank you for that: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Long_Term_Support/#Snapshots-Point-Releases. I hadn't come across the use of "Snapshot" as a synonym for point release before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that  you had held/broken packages that `sudo apt-get -f install` has fixed

You can now update the system by opening unity and running

```
update-manager
```

(Ubuntu's software updater)

Or you can run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

In a terminal.
After updating clean your system using

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And you are ready to install office with:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```